# R - concatenate rows based on conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, concatenation, tidyverse

I created a mapping table in R and have provided an example of what it looks like:

```
ex <- data.frame("id" = c(rep(1234,7)), "claim" = c(1234, 1367, 1234, 1869, 1234, 1367,1234),
             "code1" = c(24, 61, 28, 21, 20, 29,80), date = c('2019-03-18', '2019-04-12',
                                                           '2019-03-18', '2019-03-18',
                                                           '2019-03-18', '2019-04-12', '2019-03-18'),
             'code2' = c(24,29,24,24,24, 29,24), dx1=c("M234","M123",NA,"M434",NA,NA, NA),
             dx2=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"M789","Z123", "M999"),
             dx3 = c(NA,NA,"M689",NA,NA,NA, NA),
             pay = c(1000, 520, 1000, 780, 1000,520,1000))
```

Is there any way I could find a way to get this as my final output:

```
ex2 <- data.frame("id" = c(rep(1234,3)), date = c('2019-03-18', '2019-03-18','2019-04-12'),
              'code2' = c(24,24,29),
              dx1=c("M234","M434","M123"),
              dx2=c("M789",NA,"Z123"),
              dx3 = c("M689",NA,NA),
              dx4 = c("M999", NA, NA),
              pay = c(1000,780,520))
```

I basically would like for any values in dx2 or dx3 in example 1 to just be added onto the same row corresponding to that code2 value. However, if there are multiple values for code2 in dx1, then I would like to keep them as a separate row.

Is there any way I could do something like this in R?
Thanks in advance!

edit: In my mapping table (ex) there are only columns dx1, dx2, dx3. I would like for any multiple value in dx2 or dx3 to be added on as new columns (which is why in ex2 there is now a dx4 column). These changes are grouped by code2. So if there are multiple values in dx2 or dx3 for code 24, then that will determine how many new dx2 columns are created. The order can then be determined by max(pay) column.

Comment: there's no `dx4` in `ex`, but there is in `ex2`.  it looks like the `dx4` value is a multiple value for `dx2`.  can you describe more about how to handle multiple values for each `dx` type?

Comment: I included an explanation in my Q. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: thanks, that is useful info.  it is an unusual manipulation schema.  for example, if there are 2 values each for a level in `code2` for `dx1`, `dx2`, and `dx3`, you are saying you want two rows (one for each `dx1`) bu then four columns in addition to `dx1`, now `dx2-5`?  how do you decide which of the `dx2` and `dx3` values are placed in the new columns?  maybe if you could explain your use case a bit more, it'd be easier to help you find a simpler solution.

Comment: also, should the values of `dx2` and `dx3` appear only on the first row of the grouped `code2`?  or do they repeat for all rows that represent a unique `dx1`?

Comment: how should row 6 of `ex` be treated, where there is no `dx1` value, but there is a `dx2` value?  in `ex2` you put this `dx2` value on the same row as `dx1`.  but consider if there were two `dx1` values within `code2 == 29`.  how would you assign the `dx2` on a row with no `dx1`?

Comment: I had excluded a pay column before, but now I've included it. If I include a pay column, then I would want to assign any dx1 or dx2 or dx3 to a single row if they have the max pay value. Then the second dx1 would be on the second row since it's not the max pay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you require this?

```
library(tidyverse)

ex %>% pivot_longer(cols = c("dx1", "dx2", "dx3"), names_to = "code3", values_to = "val", values_drop_na = T) %>%
  arrange(claim, code2, code3) %>% group_by(id, claim, date, code2, code3) %>%
  mutate(dummy = n(),
         dummy2 = row_number(),
         code3 = ifelse(dummy >1 & dummy2 >1, "dx4", code3)) %>% arrange(code3) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c('id', 'claim', 'date', 'code2', 'pay'), names_from = 'code3', values_from = 'val', values_fn = min) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-claim)

# A tibble: 3 x 8
     id date       code2   pay dx1   dx2   dx3   dx4  
  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1  1234 2019-03-18    24  1000 M234  M789  M689  M999 
2  1234 2019-04-12    29   520 M123  Z123  NA    NA   
3  1234 2019-03-18    24   780 M434  NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: Please clarify whether there can be more than two values in either of the dx1-dx3?

Comment: Did it serve the requirement?